# How to SELECT records using MIN and MAX when multiple records exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two SQL Server tables. The first table is a customer table with customer number, name, etc. The second table contains the customer's service dates. The customer can have multiple service dates.  Here is an example of the service date table:

```
custnmbr     DateIn       DateOut
------------------------------------    
78001       1991-02-10    2001-12-07
78001       2002-08-03    2003-06-17  
78001       2006-11-22    NULL
```

I want to select the earliest DateIn and the most recent DateOut. In the example above, I would like to return the DateIn as 1991-02-10 and since the customer is currently active, I would want to return the DateOut as NULL.

This is what I have tried, but no luck

```
SELECT  
    SM.Custnmbr, 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(LH.DateIn), 101) AS DateIn, 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(LH.DateOut), 101) AS DateOut, 
FROM    
    dbo.toCustomer SM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.toLocCustHist LH ON SM.CustomerId = LH.CustomerId
GROUP BY    
    SM.CustNmbr, SM.CustName, LH.LocationId
```

When I run the query the DateIn is correct with 1991-02-10, but the DateOut has 2003-06-17, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH TEMP AS
(
SELECT  SM.Custnmbr AS Custnmbr, 
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MIN(LH.DateIn), 101) AS DateIn, 
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(ISNULL(LH.DateOut,'9999-12-12')), 101) AS DateOut, 
FROM    dbo.toCustomer SM
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.toLocCustHist LH ON SM.CustomerId = LH.CustomerId
GROUP BY    SM.CustNmbr, SM.CustName, LH.LocationId
)
SELECT Custnmbr,DateIn,
CASE WHEN DateOut='9999-12-12' THEN NULL
ELSE DateOut
END
FROM TEMP;
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` values aren't considered in aggregate functions, so you need to set the `NULL` to something else, and you shouldn't have the extra elements in your `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT  
    SM.Custnmbr, 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(LH.DateIn), 101) AS DateIn, 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(ISNULL(LH.DateOut,'2099-01-01'), 101) AS DateOut, 
FROM    
    dbo.toCustomer SM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.toLocCustHist LH ON SM.CustomerId = LH.CustomerId
GROUP BY    
    SM.CustNmbr
```

Comment: The extra elements in the group by may be relevant, depending on what the query as a whole looks like. For instance, what if several people work at more than one location and they use different machines at each of the places. Maybe we want the data that pertains to each location, but we don't care about the locations themselves. It would be appropriate to include the customer name in the group by, but not in the select.

Comment: @Jenn I'm not sure what situation it would be helpful to display the same `Custnmbr` multiple times with associated `MAX()` dates that can't be distinguished from one another, but there could be a case.

Comment: It is rare and I don't think my example fully covers it. I have seen stored procedures that are used as summaries and they use this trick. For instance, maybe I am pulling back a summary that informs the IT department of the number of machines that have been serviced in the past year and the average amount of time it took to resolve the problem. In this case, there will most likely be columns in the group by that are not in the select.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't consider a NULL date to be greater than 2003-06-17.   You need to replace NULL with a far future placeholder date for MAX() to pick it.

```
SELECT  SM.Custnmbr, 
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(LH.DateIn), 101) AS DateIn, 
CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), MAX(ISNULL(LH.DateOut,'99991231'), 101) AS DateOut, 
FROM    dbo.toCustomer SM
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.toLocCustHist LH ON SM.CustomerId = LH.CustomerId
GROUP BY    SM.CustNmbr, SM.CustName, LH.LocationId
```

If you want to display the current date (i.e. `GETDATE()`) instead of 9999-12-31, you can use a CASE statement.